# Curl - Php get element content that it's updated with ajax

Tags: php, ajax, curl, dom

I have this code:

```
$status_url = $site_properties["status_url"];
        //$listeners_url = $site_properties["listeners_url"];
        //$messages_url = $site_properties["messages_url"];
        
        //$html = file_get_html($status_url);
        
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $status_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

        $res = curl_exec($ch);

        curl_close($ch);

        $dom = new DomDocument();
        @ $dom->loadHTML($res);
        
        $radio_listeners = $dom->getElementById('listeners_cont');
        echo $radio_listeners->textContent;
```

I was wondering how can i write this script to wait a few seconds (10 for example), so the setInterval ajax in $status_url page, will be started and all the fields will be updated correctly.

Some screen shot to explain:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can’t do this with using PHP only, you have you use headless browser, take a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32532279/how-to-set-time-interval-between-page-scraping-with-phantomjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`curl` and `PHP` doesn't execute *any* javascript at all. You need something like [PhantomJS](https://phantomjs.org/) - or just get the AJAX call in your browser's network tab and implement this call only.

Comment: I found the appropriate url: http://www.caster.fm/radio_cron.php?uid=473724 Thanks!

Comment: You may find this helpful: https://api.caster.fm/docs/api-docs/account